# How to use reflection to get a constructor where you are passing in a super class as a paremeter

Tags: java, reflection, constructor, parameter-passing, extends

Today while coding I began a deep dive into the world of reflection.  I have messed with it in small bits and pieces before but never to this extent and no matter where I look I can find no answer to my question and so here I am!  Currently what I am trying to do is use reflection with a class whose constructor requests a parameter but for ease of use I wish to use the super class of the parameter.

Here is the code causing problems with some explanations:

```
this.listener = (MyListener) listenerClass.getConstructor(MyAppState.class).newInstance(this);
```

The thing is that MyAppState is the class that all of my appstates extend from and each listener takes in its own specific AppState that extends MyAppState but has extra features different from each other.  What I need to know is what I can put in my .getConstructor() to specify that the class I am passing in is the super of the parameter it wants.

Here is a theoretical example of the code:

```
this.listener = (MyListener) listenerClass.getConstructor(Class extends MyAppState.class).newInstance(this);
```

So is this possible or should I just work with my code to have a second constructor that accepts the MyAppState class, or something else along those lines.

Also, sorry if this is off topic but to prevent problems in the future, I am being told this question is subjective.  Is there any way to word future questions to not be as subjective or is the method to figure out whether the question is subjective just a bit flawed?

[EDIT] As requested, a few more examples related to the question:

```
    public MyAppState(Node screen, Class listenerClass)
    {
        this.screen = screen;

        try
        {
            this.listener = (MyListener) listenerClass.getConstructor(MyAppState.class).newInstance(this);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(MyAppState.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "The listener for the {0} appstate could not be created using reflection.", new Object[]{this.getClass().getName()});
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
```

Above is the full parent class's constructor, the said class extends one more class but it contains no constructor and so I am not sure if it is needed.  If it is please feel free to ask for it.

```
public class OptionsMenuState extends MyAppState
{
    public OptionsMenuState()
    {
        super(new Node("Options Screen"), OptionsMenuStateListener.class);
    }
```

That is one class and its constructor with pieces cut off to keep it short.

```
public class MainMenuState extends MyAppState
{
    public MainMenuState()
    {
        super(new Node("Start Screen"), MainMenuStateListener.class);
    }
```

Here is another class and its constructor.

[EDIT] As suggested, I created a program that roughly mimics what I am attempting to do.

/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        //This is what I want to do but I don't know how to have java allow me to pass in Greeting.
        createObject(SimpleSentence.class);
        createObject(DifferentSentence.class);
    }

    public static void createObject(Class theClass)
    {
        theClass.getConstructor(Greeting.class).newInstance(new Hello());
    }

    class SimpleSentence
    {
        Hello firstWord;

        public SimpleSentence(Hello word)
        {
            firstWord = word;
        }
    }

    class DifferentSentence
    {
        Howdy firstWord;

        public DifferentSentence(Howdy word)
        {
            firstWord = word;
        }
    }

    class Greeting
    {

    }

    class Hello extends Greeting
    {

    }

    class Howdy extends Greeting
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Please give an example of a constructor, of its parameter, and the inheritance hierarchy you are describing.

Comment: Just edited the question with the information about halfway down.

Comment: Your question is still unclear. Your question includes 5 types, without describing the type hierarchy. I'm sure you could demonstrate the problem with a short but complete program which would be significantly clearer.

Comment: And what is `listenerClass`? Is there an inheritance hierarchy with that type too?

Comment: Adding an example that is much simpler I hope and that poses a similar problem.  Sorry for the lack of constructors and body to the example but it is late by me but don't want to leave this question overnight if it is not complete but I also need to get some sleep.

Comment: I hope you see how your example will fail since you will invoke a constructor that expects a `Howdy` by providing a `Hello`.

Comment: I do see how my example will fail.  I can't really figure out a way to make the example work the way I wrote it and I think it will become complicated to rewrite it.  The real question is how to get the .getConstructor(Greeting.class) part to work as I would never even get to the problem of passing a Hello when it expects a Howdy as there is no constructor that has a Greeting parameter but only parameters that extend greeting.  I need some way, if it exists, to specify that I want a constructor that allows passing in of a parameter that extends Greeting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is you can't. `getConstructor(Class<?>...parametertypes)` is very explicit because it needs to match exactly zero or one constructor only.

You will need to go through all the constructors to find one, that has a parameter that is assignable from `MyAppState`

e.g. outline:

```
    final Constructor<?>[] ctrs = listenerClass.getConstructors();
    for (Constructor<?> constructor : ctrs) {
        if (constructor.getParameterTypes()[0].isAssignableFrom(MyAppState.class)) {
            // use this one?
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think this may be the answer I need.  Thank you for understanding my seemingly complicated question.  As long as there is no easier way to do what I want I think you figured it out!

Comment: Just beware that you potentially may find many constructors that could match your criteria, so make sure your documentation is very specific in your requirements. Anything you can do to make it more explicit would be good (such as requiring a certain constructor annotation or something)